# Sql query result

Tags: sql

what would be the result of following query?

```
select StudentName from Students where StudentName LIKE '[^R-X]%'

select StudentName from Students where StudentName = '[^R-X]%
```

thanks

Comment: I am in confusion. Please check my question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Students who's name is not starting with `R`,`S`,`T`,`U`,`V`,`W` or `X`

The difference between the 2 queries is that the first is correct and the second not. You can use wildcards (`%`) only with the `like` operator.

Comment: Thanks alot for quick responce. will accept your answer, But it will allow me to accept after 8 min.

Comment: Please check my question again. what is the difference between in those queries? what would be the output of those>

Answer (score 0):

All Studunts, which Studentname not begins with r,s,t,u,v,w or x.

Comment: You changed the case of characters from upper case in the question to lower case in your answer, therefore your statement does not hold true if the collation is case sensitive.